# http-auth digest using express js

Tags: node.js, express, http-auth

I'm developing an API in Express JS. I want to use [http-auth library](https://github.com/http-auth/http-auth) and I've been trying to use digest authentication, but I have not been able to use it. Here is my code:

```
var app        = require('express')(),
    routes     = require('./routes'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    auth       = require('http-auth'); 

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // Soporta json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ // Soporta encoded bodies
    extended: true
}));

var digest = auth.digest({
    realm: 'prueba',
    file: __dirname + "/usr.pass"
});

app.use(auth.connect(digest));

// Conectamos todas nuestras rutas
app.use('/', routes);

// Levantamos servidor
app.listen(9999, () => {
    Console.log('running');
});
```

My `usr.pass` file has this line: `jdurini:prueba:88bfcf02e7f554f9e9ea350b699bc6a7` (password is a MD5 representation por '2315').

I'm using POSTMAN to call my endpoints. In this case, I'm trying POST method on `localhost:9999`, and everytime I try, It goes to digest.on('fail') event.

In the **Authorization** tab, I [use this data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzPxg.png).

What am I doing wrong? This is my first time using Express, so any comment could be helpful.

#### Edit 1 - August 14th

Authorization header in postman is as follows:`Digest username="jdurini", realm="prueba", nonce="", uri="/", response="2c01bce3e1980c575fc82e32f9943617", opaque=""` . This header is autogenerated when I fill Authorization's form with:

- **type**: Digest Auth
- **username**: jdurini
- **Realm**: prueba
- **Password**: 2315

No other header is used in the request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Reason

Looks like there is a problem with your authentication file.

### Soluton

I just re-generated authentication line with [htdigest](https://github.com/http-auth/htdigest/):

```
htdigest usr.pass prueba jdurini
```

and got something like this:

```
jdurini:prueba:546bb2109e9d875fb486bf90a55fdbd6
```

And new version works for me.

### Notice

I guess you may want to change `Console.log('running')` line to lower case, as your version does not compile for me.

Comment: Thanks for your awnser.

I used htdigest to generate my password file. But it keeps returning "401 Unauthorized" in Postman

Comment: Give me more info on request, response headers please.

Comment: for difference try with simple browser to verify if that is not a problem related  to Postman configuration.

Comment: It worked in Chrome! Thanks @gevorg. What do you think is the problem with postman?

Comment: The problem is that postman ignores nonce sent by server and hardcodes the one provided by you.

Comment: see https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/932, it is a postman bug

Comment: I see... One last question. Which Algorithm uses htdigest for password encryption? I thought it was MD5 but neigher MySQL or [this page](http://www.md5.cz/) return this hash: `546bb2109e9d875fb486bf90a55fdbd6`, they return this one: `88bfcf02e7f554f9e9ea350b699bc6a7`.

Comment: it is md5, however it depends what you put into input:  utils.md5(`${username}:${realm}:${password}`)

Comment: oh, I see... it applies MD5 to those fields.. thanks!