# Digest authentication in nodejs

Tags: node.js, digest-authentication

I'm using the [urllib npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/urllib) with the following code:

```
options = {
    method: 'GET',
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    digestAuth: `${user}:${pass}`
}

urllib.request(uri, options, function (err, data, res) {
    if (err) {
        throw err; // you need to handle error
    }
    console.log(res.statusCode);
    console.log(res.headers);
    // data is Buffer instance
    console.log(data.toString());
})
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting a 401 error back:

> 401
> {   'content-length': '222',   'content-type': 'text/plain',
> connection: 'close',   'www-authenticate': 'Digest
> realm="000f7c16eacc", nonce="8652e7dfa50f6124896b84142eef93b5",
> stale="false", algorithm="MD5", qop="auth"',   'x-frame-options':
> 'SAMEORIGIN' }
> { "Response": {
> "ResponseURL": "/images/snapshot.jpg",
> "ResponseCode": 3,
> "SubResponseCode": 0,
> "ResponseString": "Not Authorized",
> "StatusCode": 401,
> "StatusString": "Unauthorized",
> "Data": "null" } }

The same uri, username, and password works when accessing via postman.  What configuration details am I missing in this request?  urllib doesn't provide a digest auth example.

I am not married to urllib and will take any working nodejs solution for pulling an image from an digest-auth endpoint.

Comment: From the response you'are getting, it doesn't appear to be any problem with your code. Getting http 401 means your credentials are not valid.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work as it is recommended answer for similar questions.

Are you sure your user name and password is correct ?

[use urllib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45638284/http-auth-digest-using-express-js)

Following code sample works perfectly for me. only when username and password is incorrect then I get similar error as you.

client.js

```
const httpClient = require("urllib");

const user = "ankit";
const pass = "ankit";

const uri = "http://localhost:1337";
options = {
  method: "GET",
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
  digestAuth: `${user}:${pass}`,
};

httpClient.request(uri, options, function (err, data, res) {
  if (err) {
    throw err; // you need to handle error
  }
  console.log(res.statusCode);
  console.log(res.headers);
  // data is Buffer instance
  console.log(data.toString());
});
```

server.js

```
var http = require("http");
var auth = require("http-auth");

var digest = auth.digest({
  realm: "Sample",
  file: __dirname + "/users.htpasswd",
  algorithm: "md5",
});

http
  .createServer(
    digest.check((req, res) => {
      res.end(`Welcome to private area - ${req.user}!`);
    })
  )
  .listen(1337, () => {
    // Log URL.
    console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/");
  });
```

users.htpasswd

```
ankit:Sample:e4b2d19b03346a1c45ce86ad41b85c5e
```

[sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47631570/digest-auth-using-http-auth)

Comment: user/pass are correct.  I managed to get it solved using the request library. (which is weirdly deprecated for being 'too popular').  I never was able to get URLLIB to work, though I will try copy-paste of your code just to verify.

Comment: A copy/paste of the above code did not work.  But no one else answered, so I gave you the bounty anyway.

Comment: Thanks but I am surprised it would not. It was hence I pasted it. :\